# jpa, more then one primary key

Tags: google-app-engine, jpa

I have an Article entity and an ArticleCode entity. Aritcle Code has Article as forgeing key but is has also a second and third primary key.

The example below isnt possible because Article isnt serializable. Any ideas?

Thanks,
Ralph

@Entity
public class Article {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.TABLE)
    private Long id;

```
public Long getId() { return id; }
```

}

@Entity
@IdClass(com.google.gwt.sample.stockwatcher.server.huflattich.ArticleCode.ComposedIdKey.class)
public class ArticleCode {

```
@Id
@OneToOne
private Article article;

@Id
@Column(name="coding_system")
private String codingSystem;

@Id
private String code;

...

public static class ComposedIdKey implements Serializable {
    public Article article;
    public String codingSystem;
    public String code;

    public ComposedIdKey () { }

    public ComposedIdKey(Article article, String codingSystem, String code) {
        this.article = article;
        this.codingSystem = codingSystem;
        this.code = code;
    }

     ...
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

ohh, in google's BigTable it is impossible to have more then one primary key.